# Why would anybody use "bloody" to describe how would they take their burgers or any other food?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, context, sense-verbs

I think it doesn't make sense to go over to the bar and ask for a burger, and then when the bartender replies "How would you like your burger", to answer "bloody" (I saw this in a movie but also heard someone use the word to describe their food).

I know that "bloody" is sometimes used for intensity, but what could it actually mean related to the concept of intensity when it's been used to describe a food item?

It doesn't makes any sense because there are many words that could be used, like "raw" (no "external/extra" processes done to the burger).

Is there any other sense of "bloody" that has been overlooked when using it in the context of food items?

Comment: You probably already know, but distaste for the word "bloody" is likely a regional thing. Use of this word as an expletive is very uncommon in the USA.

Comment: I have heard it used humorously to describe rare or blue meat but I don't think it is ever used seriously.

Comment: "Bloody" is just slang for rare. It was famously used in *Pulp Fiction*. When John Travolta ordered a steak, Steve Buscemi gave him the choice of it being prepared "burnt to a crisp" or "bloody as hell".

Comment: That literal sense of ‘_bloody_’ is usually not considered vulgar, even when the other meanings are.

Comment: Shock value. :-)

Comment: The passive voice in your last sentence is odd, since what you seem to mean is "Is there any other sense that *I* have overlooked?"

Comment: I like a well-done question myself, so voting to reopen. *Why* a native speaker would say "bloody steak/burger" is not something you could look up in any dictionary.

Comment: Interesting that you find the word strange. I have learned much of my English from a Texan and find *bloody* perfectly natural. A steak that's *bloody* oozes red fluid; it is literally *bloody.*

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Technically that red liquid is liquid from the muscle fibers colored by myoglobin, it's not the stuff found in blood vessels, so such a steak is not *literally* bloody (assuming you meant literal in the literal sense and not the figurative).

Comment: I am somewhat confused as to why it "doesn't make sense". Hyperbole is a thing. Is it not a well known literary/rhetorical device?

Comment: @gidds In the US, it's not considered vulgar at all, but then we mostly only use it in the literal sense.  (Not that we don't understand the way it's used in the UK, but that usage will instantly mark you as a Brit/Aussie even if your American accent is pretty convincing otherwise.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman One of the structures forming the [Tower Of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_London) is known as the ‘Bloody Tower’, on account of the blood supposed to have been spilled there. My brother and I visited it when very young, and I remember gleefully repeating its name as often as possible, because it was the only occasion we were allowed to use the word ‘bloody’ :-) (I think we had similar fun on discovering the cocktail [‘Bloody Mary’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Mary_(cocktail))…)

Comment: @gidds You could have read Shakespeare: for example in *Henry IV part 2* you get "bloody field", "bloody state", "bloody Douglas", "bloody courses", "bloody-faced", "bloody youth", "bloody insurrection", "bloody book", "bloody day"

Comment: “It doesn't makes any sense because there are many words that could be used, like "raw".” The existence of terms does not preclude the existence of equivalent terms.

Comment: @Henry I love Shakespeare's definition of a computer program: “Bloody instructions, which being taught return to plague the inventor.” [_Macbeth_, Act 1, Scene 7]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That sense of *bloody* means *undercooked*, so much so that pink juice comes out of it when a fork is put in it. The pink juice isn't exactly blood, but the expression is an exaggeration.

Comment: Ohk, I see, you're saying about myoglobin https://www.google.com/search?q=red+juice+coming+out+of+burger right ?

Comment: @VickyDev Yes, that's right, it’s myoglobin. They're saying they want their meat cooked "extra rare".

Comment: Thanks @tchrist for yet another phrase

Comment: "Walking away".

Comment: @HotLicks Or, *still mooing*.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty or *still twitching*.

Comment: For a steak (not normally a burger) the "formal" or "technical" (or "self-satisfied" depending on your pov) term for this is _'Blue'_.

Comment: My dad's a large-animal veterinarian, and he wouldn't order it that way, but he's gotten a very rare cook at least once and said, "I have my bag, I think I can save it".

Comment: "pink juice comes out of it when a fork is put in it" this is how steak is almost always cooked, rare/medium rare, so why does "bloody" mean "undercooked"?

Comment: @theonlygusti "bloody" can mean *extra* rare, but anyway definitions of "rare" vary.  [This article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/food-and-drink/scotch-beef/how-do-you-like-your-steak/) has blue/bleu, which we could equate to "bloody" as only 29°C inside which isn't even really warm, while rare has a wide range of  30--50°C.  Others would disagree at the top end of that range

Comment: @theonlygusti Americans come in two rather opposed camps when it comes to steak and one of them has a long tradition of overcooking things to death out of fear.  What the rest of the world considers "medium rare" seems to be considered "nearly still alive" by the standards of this group.  Calling a rare steak "bloody" is a bit of a light jibe that only makes sense if you're coming at it with certain preconceptions about what a cooked steak should look like.

Comment: @J... The group in the US that like their beef steaks cooked to the point of ruination has one other weird attribute: They tend to douse their ruined piece of expensive meat with ketchup. I don't get it, but to each their own.

Comment: @theonlygusti If the juices that come out of a beef steak are just pink (as opposed to reddish), that means that the steak overcooked to some Americans. On the other hand, if there's the slightest twinge of pinkness to those juices, that means that the steak is undercooked to other Americans.  American preferences regarding how steaks should be cooked is markedly bimodal.

Answer (score 16):

An explanation for why some people say *bloody* to describe [doneness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doneness) could be an incorrect, literal translation from another language.

For example, "rare" is called *[saignant](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/saignant)* ("bloody") in French, and [*al sangue*](https://it.glosbe.com/it/en/una%20bistecca%20al%20sangue) in Italian.

Comment: Note that the literal translation for “_saignant_” would be “_bleeding_”, “_bloody_” would be a translation for “_sanglant_” or “_ensanglanté_”

Comment: @DidierL Possibly, yes. Since we're talking about an incorrect translation anyway, I'm not sure there needs to be a "correct incorrect" translation. For what it's worth, I've already heard French people try to order a "bloody steak", and get amused or puzzled looks in return.

Comment: Oh I wouldn’t be surprised to hear French-speaking people say that (it’s my mother tongue too), it’s just that your answer says “literal” 

Comment: @DidierL Some wordbooks seem to agree : https://www.wordreference.com/fren/saignant I've updated the answer to make it clear it's incorrect. Do you agree with how it's written now?

Comment: And, to add to it, a plethora of other languages. Although I never did a formal collection, I'd venture to say that many, if not most languages actually refer to something blood-related when speaking about rare steaks. Which is hardly surprising, actually, given what it is and how it is done. :-)

Comment: @Gábor: I only checked 5 languages. Do you have any other example?

Comment: Hungarian, for example. As in those other languages, calling it "bloody" has no negative connotation at all, it's just natural considering that a rare steak _is_ bloody.

Comment: @Gábor: I think it's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoglobin, and not blood.

Comment: @EricDuminil A steak cooked to barely rare will have a lot of red liquid seeping from it. Strictly speaking, yes, it's not blood. Most people however don't know that it isn't blood, and if you try to explain the difference between blood and that red liquid, you'll be called a bloody a$$hole in Great Britain. Because "bloody" in the US doesn't have the negative connotation that it has in other parts of the English speaking world, you're likely to hear "bloody" replaced with the F-bomb in American English.

Comment: @DavidHammen: True. I forgot to add <pedantic> tag.

Comment: @EricDuminil you're probably right. However, when was this discovered? I'm quite certain our culinary naming predates it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

To make the person who's saying it sound like a strong, tough carnivore.

Example:

"How would you like your steak, sir?" the waiter asked Mike. Mike pushed back on his boots, leaned back in his chair, raised the brim of his cowboy hat so he could look into the waiter's eye.

"Bloody." Mike replied. "The only way steak should be eaten."

Comment: Yes, this is something other answers have missed -- it signals to the audience that this is a tough-guy character; but you could make it a complete sentence and expand on the cultural aspect?

Answer (score 3):

All of this response is about how things are in the United States.

There is no other sense in which "bloody" is used to refer to a food item, and the term "bloody" is reserved exclusively for beef products.  One can refer to a burger, a steak, or any other beef-based product as being served "bloody".  There is no authoritative description of the meaning of this term in the American lexicon.  What is happening here, is an over-exaggeration of the desired state of the served meat.  The individual ordering their beef prepared "bloody" is accomplishing several things in one apparently simple statement.  First, the obvious:  they are requesting that their beef product be served as rare as possible under the circumstances.  Second, the expressing a lifelong ennui which cannot be dispelled by any means.  Additionally, they may be expressing a type of "alpha male" mentality that requires them to demonstrate their manhood at any given opportunity in a variety of interesting and expressive manners.

Simply put, the guy (it's almost always a guy) ordering his meat "bloody" really just means he's that he's unhappy and wants his beef rare.

Experiences in other countries may vary wildly.

Comment: Is medium rare not considered to be "bloody" by americans?

Comment: No.  Rare rare is considered bloody by Americans.  But again, it's a machismo thing, so YMMV

Comment: Re *it's almost always a guy*. That's not my experience. I have a sister in law who wants her steaks "still mooing". It was a female coworker who convinced me to try beef tatami at a local Japanese restaurant, and another who convinced me to try beef tartare at a different restaurant.

Comment: @theonlygusti "Bloody" generally means "as rare as I can get it".  Usually that isn't medium-rare.

Comment: @DavidHammen as I said, "Your mileage may vary"

Comment: Depending on the restaurant you go to, good luck getting anything less than medium, no matter what you tell them you want.

Comment: @DavidHammen i do believe the "it's always a guy" refers to the *specific* phrasing of "bloody meat" - since of course there are numerous places where rare(r) meat is a delicacy. plus i do believe raw meat is in fact, not rare at all. no more than well done can be called rare, at least.

Comment: This is really just a peeve about perceived American motives.

Answer (score 1):

Exaggerating how bloody or only newly killed the beef may be are requests for increasingly rare cooking. Such descriptions can get absurd. "He looked at my rare steak and said, 'I seen them hurt worse than that, get up and run away'".

Terms for cooking meat are Rare, Medium and Well-Done. Gradations of this, not mine but from Samson's Paddock https://medium.com/@samsonspaddockau/whats-the-difference-between-rare-medium-and-well-done-steak-fe463e0f960f

are as follows:
Rare; 1 minute each side

Medium Rare; 2 minute each side

Medium; 3 minute each side

Medium Well; 4 minute each side

Well; 5 minute each side

Rare refers to a steak that’s been cooked for a very short period of time — leaving the centre cool and red in colour. It’s just a stage up from raw meat — but cooked on the outside. Steak doesn’t contain parasites that chicken and pork do — eating it rare doesn’t pose any health risks.

From https://medium.com/@samsonspaddockau/whats-the-difference-between-rare-medium-and-well-done-steak-fe463e0f960f

Comment: I don't think the parasites that chickens get can be passed on to humans as bacteria can (e.g., Salmonella).

Comment: On the other end of the scale if someone wants it "very well done", they sometimes self-deprecatingly say something like "incinerated" (I think to head off at the pass the jokes at their expense for liking their steak done the 'wrong' way)

Comment: Diners in my country (USA) would generally be ill advised to order a burger on  the rare side (and many eateries refuse to serve them), since our slaughterhouses, aiming for cheapness at all costs, routinely contaminate the cut surfaces of meats, and the grinding distributes the contamination.

Comment: Steak is a different matter, but timing for each gradation will vary with both with the thickness of the steak and the heat source. Doneness of meat is better measured by thermometer than stopwatch.

Comment: @BrianDonovan yeah, a thin "sizzler" steak from the supermarket will get well done in the time it'd take to get a decent filet mignon warmed up and rare. For a given cut & thickness though a stopwatch can be a reasonable guide though (provided you have a fairly normal heat source, and not an extremely strong or weak one). I don't know about where you are, but here (UK), steaks in the supermarket usually have cooking times on them that are fairly accurate (and obviously vary by cut and thickness)

Comment: @Tristan burgers are another matter though.  Preparation/handling of the meat that is to be minced is important, as it is with steak tartare

Comment: [Your last sentence is plain wrong.](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/taeniasis/gen_info/faqs.html).

Comment: It is sad that despite showing the source of the quote I am responsible for the content. It is not My last sentence. If you have a source of your own you may site it here. If we cannot have civil discussions on cooking steak then I have little hope for more important topics.

Answer (score -1):

Cooking meat:

- well done, medium rare, rare, very rare or bloody

very rare = bloody. Very unusual in NA and UK, etc.

In French cooking, this level of cooking (barely allowing the meat to sit on the grill or in the pan so the outside is browned or seared) is called **bleu**. Very often, when meat is cooked like this, it still has blood in it.

**A lexicon for ordering your steak in France**

> Bleu –  (Pronounced ble).This is an extraordinarily rare steak,
> **singed outside and bloody inside.** [very rare or bloody]
> Saignant – (Pronounced say-nyon, do not pronounce the T).  The French term for a rare steak.  [rare]
> À Point - (Pronounced ah pwa). Perfectly cooked.  À point is used in the French kitchen for any food perfectly cooked, not just steaks!
> Forget what the guidebook says.  For a steak,  a point does not mean
> medium-rare! When an Italian chef wants perfect pasta, he or she will
> say al dente. In France for the same perfect pasta, a French chef
> would say à point: perfectly cooked. A steak in France cooked “ à
> point,”  will be rare-to-medium-rare, with the accent on the rare.
> Rare-to-medium-rare is how the majority of Frenchmen and women prefer
> their steak and that is "à point", perfectly cooked.** [Medium rare]

[ordering steak in French](https://behind-the-french-menu.blogspot.com/2012/05/behind-french-menu.html)

Please note: The degrees of cookedness in French and English **are not equivalent.**
**Generally speaking**, the French never eat their meat well done. That is a faux pas. (Of course, there will always be someone who does eat their meat well done (bien cuit) in France. Never say never). Generally speaking, in NA or the UK, one doesn't eat one's meat "bloody". However, one could say that to describe very rare, if one wanted to.

[Please note: I quoted the text above, **with guidance to pronunciation in French that is wrong,** for the explanations. Please do not edit the mistakes. I don't think mistakes should be edited. ]

Comment: note, a very rare steak is actually extremely unlikely to contain actual blood. The "blood" you see when you cut into a blue steak is actually myoglobin. The actual blood will have been drained at the abattoir. I think you're also underestimating the number of Anglophones who like their meat saignant or even bleu. It's certainly much less common than in France, and the proportion who'd eat their meat ~~ruined~~ well done is certainly much higher, but there are a fair few of us who want the inside pretty much uncooked

Comment: "ah pwa" ("à pois") would mean "spotted", and "say-nyon" ("saigons") would be imperative form of bleed, first person plural ("let us bleed", more or less). Saying that "à point" is perfectly cooked is subjective, too. Also note that "bien cuit" is how you would order "well done". It is indeed odd, but it happens.

Comment: @njzk2 who said à pois? It's **à point**. **saignant** is an adjective. Saignons=is the imperative form of bleed, not: "saigons". **If you are going to criticize, try to get your spelling and words right**.

Comment: @Tristan Whatever. That is not the main point. I am not underestimating anything. Very rare does not even equate to bleu. In English, there is A, B, C, D and in French: B, C, D and E. In other words, in French, well done is not in the chart, as it were.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm pointing out that if you pronounce "ah pwa", you're saying "à pois", not "à point". "Saigons" is a typo, sorry about that. The point remains that if you are saying "say-nyon", you are saying "saignons", not "saignant".

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah, the mistake was not mine.

Comment: @njzk2 You're correct: Lambie used bad spelling-pronunciations; compare [*saignons*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saignons) with its /õ/. In French, [*saignant*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saignant#Pronunciation) is /sɛ.ɲɑ̃/ with no "o" sound just nasalized "ɑ"; [*à point*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_point##Pronunciation) is /ɑ pwɛ̃/ with no "a" sound just nasalized open "ɛ"; and [*bleu*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleu#Pronunciation) is /blø/ where [ø is the close-mid front rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_rounded_vowel) as heard in FR *peu*.

Comment: I quoted someone who did. The point was about the content, not how to pronounce the French. **I did not use those spelling pronunciations. They are in a text I quoted!** I was looking to post the explanations not the pronunciations. And the blog writer may have made a "mistake" but using the alphabet to show pronunciation is a mess, at best. In fact, the explanations are fine.

Comment: Sorry about that. I couldn't tell that those were quoted text. It looks better now.

Comment: @tchrist I know the pronunciation stuff is stupid. But I really like his explanation.

Comment: A month ago a UK chef friend of mine told me he likes his steaks "bloody" with emphasis. I asked back "blue?". He nodded in agreement... +1 for answering "Is there any other sense of "bloody" that has been overlooked... ".